# python: производительность eval

Tags: python, python-3.x, производительность, eval

подскажите, есть ли какие-то техники повышения производительности eval?

в eval передаются математические выражения для вычисления (без переменных, но с возможностью вызова математических функций)

Comment: `eval` - просто выполняет python код из строки. Если нужно оптимизировать много функций `eval` подряд то есть ответ на основном stackoverflow [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12467570/python-way-to-speed-up-a-repeatedly-executed-eval-statement)

Comment: предложенный способ не помог, наоборот, замедлил
наверное потому что у меня очень легкие выражения (несколько арифметических операций), просто их много